# Facebookアプリのテスト環境→本番環境移行について

Tags: java, api, oauth, facebook

テスト環境にて、Facebook APIのレビュー承認が下りたため、本番環境での使用をする予定なのですが、クライアントOAuth設定でホワイトリストに追加されていない旨のエラーが出て困っています。

本番環境で使用できるようにするにあたり、developers.facebook.comでアプリの情報について
下記の項目を修正しています。

・設定＞ベーシック
アプリドメインを本番ドメインに変更
プライバシーポリシーのURL、利用規約のURLを本番ドメインに変更
ウェブサイトのサイトURLを本番ドメインに変更

・プロダクト＞設定
有効なOAuthリダイレクトUR

FB連携の実装は、Facebook4jを使用しています。
テスト環境と異なるのはドメイン名だけで、ドメイン名以下のURLは全く同じなので
何がいけないのかと途方に暮れています。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
URLはブロックされています: リダイレクトURIがアプリのクライアントOAuth設定でホワイトリストに追加されていないため、リダイレクトできませんでした。クライアントとウェブOAuthログインをオンにして、すべてのアプリドメインを有効なOAuthリダイレクトURIとして追加してください。
```

**試したこと**
・developers.facebook.comで有効なOAuthリダイレクトURIの設定

Answer (score 1):

Facebookのクライアントの設定の「有効なOAuthリダイレクトURI」とクライアントが送信するリクエストの「redirect_uri」パラメーターが一致していないのではないですか？

例えば、クライアントが「テスト環境」で使用していたときと同じ「redirect_uri」パラメーターをそのまま送っているとか。